# How do I get the value from an option in tkinter after it has passed through a function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to create an option menu for a user to interact with, when the selection has been made it will pass through a function to return an integer based on the input. I want to be able to return the integer back to a variable outside of the function so it can be received by another file. My problem is that python will keep returning the button as the command has not yet been processed.

```
from tkinter import *
Final = [] ##List containing options

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(Final[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *Final)
w.pack()

def ok():
    global choice
    choice =  variable.get()

    global x
    x = 0
    for i in Final:
        if str(i) == str(choice):
            break
        x += 1


button = Button(master, text="Choose", command=ok)
button.pack()
values = x
```

Comment: you have value in global variable `x` so you don't need another variable `values`. You may only create `x` at start with some default value.

Comment: `Button` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for you click. It only inform tkinter that you want to see button in window. And `mainloop()` create window and display button in this window. If you need value after closing window then use `values = x` after `mainloop()`

Comment: @furas if the button has been clicked do I use destroy() to stop it? I want it to check whether it has been clicked so I can then go on to destroy

Comment: when button is clicked then it runs function `ok` and inside `ok` you can destroy whatever you want.